# Is the following code seeding OpenSSL's PRNG necessary, superfluous, or harmful?

Tags: openssl, random

As I was going through [Crypt::SSLeay](https://github.com/nanis/Crypt-SSLeay), preparing it for the next release, I noticed the following code, written way before my time,

```
...

int rand_bytes_read;
static int bNotFirstTime;
char buf[ 1024 ];

...

if(!bNotFirstTime) {
    SSLeay_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    bNotFirstTime = 1;
}

/**** Code from ..., 10/3/2002 ****/
/**** Use /dev/urandom to seed if available  ****/
rand_bytes_read = RAND_load_file("/dev/urandom", 1024);
if (rand_bytes_read <= 0) {
    /* Couldn't read /dev/urandom, just seed off
     * of the stack variable (the old way)
     */
    RAND_seed(buf,sizeof buf);
}
```

First, it seems to me that the correct way to check if `RAND_load_file` succeeded is to check if bytes read is equal to bytes requested.

Leaving that aside, it is my understanding that `SSL_library_init` does seed the PRNG from `/dev/urandom` if it is available, and from other sources on Windows etc.

- Is there a reason to try to re-seed the PRNG every time a new context is created (`SSL_library_init` is only invoked the first time)?
- Is using the contents of a stack variable an acceptable way to provide randomness?

[OpenSSL's Wiki](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Initialization) states:

> Initialization
>
> OpenSSL will attempt to seed the random number generator automatically upon instantiation by calling `RAND_poll`. `RAND_poll` seeds the random number generator using a system-specific entropy source, which is `/dev/urandom` on UNIX-like operating systems, and is a combination of `CryptGenRandom` and other sources of entropy on Windows.
>
> Be careful when deferring to `RAND_poll` on some Unix systems because it does not seed the generator. See the code guarded with `OPENSSL_SYS_VXWORKS` in rand_unix.c. Additionally, `RAND_poll` can have negative interactions on newer Windows platforms, so your program could hang or crash depending on the potential issue. See Windows Issues below.

PS: `Crypt::SSLeay` provides support for Perl's [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) to communicate over HTTPS. [It is no longer used by default](http://blog.nu42.com/2014/04/does-your-code-really-depend-on.html), but it is maintained so as not to break older setups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With current and not-so-current versions of OpenSSL, this code is useless (but harmless), because OpenSSL will automatically seed itself on `/dev/urandom` on machines where `/dev/urandom` is available. This is [documented](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_add.html):

> On systems that provide /dev/urandom, the randomness device is used to seed the PRNG transparently. However, on all other systems, the application is responsible for seeding the PRNG by calling RAND_add(), RAND_egd() or RAND_load_file().

Actually, the documentation is slightly wrong because on Windows, where there is no `/dev/urandom`, OpenSSL uses `CryptGenRandom()`, so the automatic strong seeding still occurs.

On machines where there is no system-provided strong PRNG, the caller must provide entropy "manually", but these systems are, by definition, machines where there is no `/dev/urandom`.

The contents of an uninitialized stack variable are hardly a good source of entropy, because such contents are usually very deterministic. Reasonable sources of randomness in a machine come from the "physical world", typically precise timings of hardware events.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure it is harmless, though. With this code, on a Windows system, OpenSSL will seed via `CryptGenRandom`, and then this code will obliterate it with the contents of `buf`. My instinct is to remove it. What do you think?

Comment: `RAND_seed()` does not _replace_ the internal state, it _adds_ to the entropy. Internally, the mixing is done with a hash function (or something similar). Thus, an application which does useless things (as the one you show) cannot destroy its own security that way (and that is a blessing, because applications often do stupid things when randomness is involved).

Comment: I had missed that. Thank you very much for pointing it out.